# How to measure the performance of an Ionic 5 + Angular 10 Mobile App?

Tags: angular, performance, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm working with a Ionic 5 + Angular 10 Mobile App and I would like to measure the performance in general. I was taking a look at Lighthouse but seems more appropriate for a Web Application, What is the best practice to do so for an Ionic Mobile App?

Comment: their is nothing that would give you a good measure of performance. The only way i use in my apps is to test the app on an android device with sdk 23 or 24 which is considered with low performance devices, dont try to test performance on ios as ios is more performant and faster than android so make your tests based on android.. and check page opening delays and such things, and after you enhance your app, you will be pretty sure it will be perfect as native on newer android sdk or on any ios device

Comment: @MostafaHarb but how can I take precise measure of the time of opening delay? What method or technique did you use to measure time delays before and after the enhancement? thx!

Comment: no standard way, usually when you open a page it should open fast then data should be loading according to http response time, once the page open you need to check if their is a delay in opening the page, and if their is slow rendering.. same when opening a modal or same when opening an alert.. in a native app they should open instantly, so you check are they the same in your app!! if not then you will need to start integrating things to make it perfect.. also if loading big list of data (sure with pagination) but after scrolling much u need to check if that is causing device to be overheated

Comment: so in few words, measuring your app is expecting to have exactly a native behavior, if not, then the performance is high and you will need to do integration to fix things.. lighthouse measures the performance on web and still don't give exact result and still just for web not for mobile, since browser webview can have bigger amount of memory to handle while mobile app have small amount.. so really only use android device to check over things..